# Do Xamarin solutions integrate with Windows RT?

Tags: xamarin

I am considering switching to building applications using Xamarin in C# to allow for integration between tablets and Windows RT. Currently we are using WPF.

Would we be able to use Xamarin products on Windows RT?

Are there any limitations to developing a solution which would work for both tablet (iPad, Android) and Windows RT?

Comment: I don't see why this was closed. Anyway, the answer is "kind of". As you know, Xamarin lets you code a UI layer in C# for Android and iOS. You can already code in C# for RT - you don't need Xamarin. So the idea is that you will end up with a common C# layer, and then separate view layers for iOS, Android and RT. See http://propertycross.com/xamarin/